# Invalid-Grant by trying to read a value from Googl-Cloud-Storage

Tags: java, spring, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

im trying to to read a value from Google-Cloud storage from my Spring application. I use the Spring Cloud GCP extension to work with Google Cloud Storage.
My Pom.xml for the gcp dependency:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-storage</artifactId> 
 <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

When i try to read a file from my rest-endpoint i get the exception(at the end of my answer) that somehow that my token could not be refreshed ? Where i can set my clientId or is there something else going on ? I used the code from the sample application which is provided by pivotal and google.

```
@RestController
public class GCloudStorageController {

    @Value("gs://test_files_test/test.txt")
    private Resource gcsFile;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/cloud", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String readGcsFile() throws IOException {
        return StreamUtils.copyToString(
                this.gcsFile.getInputStream(),
                Charset.defaultCharset()) + "\n";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/cloud", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    String writeGcs(@RequestBody String data) throws IOException {
        try (OutputStream os = ((WritableResource) this.gcsFile).getOutputStream()) {
            os.write(data.getBytes());
        }
        return "file was updated\n";
    }
}
```

```
2019-08-20 20:27:02.555 DEBUG 12348 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Failed to complete request: com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
2019-08-20 20:27:02.556 DEBUG 12348 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@24f1dc0f
2019-08-20 20:27:02.557 DEBUG 12348 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2019-08-20 20:27:02.557 DEBUG 12348 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2019-08-20 20:27:02.563 ERROR 12348 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}] with root cause

com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1094) ~[google-http-client-1.30.1.jar:na]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.UserCredentials.refreshAccessToken(UserCredentials.java:193) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.16.1.jar:na]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.refresh(OAuth2Credentials.java:165) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.16.1.jar:na]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getRequestMetadata(OAuth2Credentials.java:151) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.16.1.jar:na]
    at com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter.initialize(HttpCredentialsAdapter.java:96) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.16.1.jar:na]
    at com.google.cloud.http.HttpTransportOptions$1.initialize(HttpTransportOptions.java:159) ~[google-cloud-core-http-1.79.0.jar:1.79.0]
    at com.google.cloud.http.CensusHttpModule$CensusHttpRequestInitializer.initialize(CensusHttpModule.java:109) ~[google-cloud-core-http-1.79.0.jar:1.79.0]
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory.buildRequest(HttpRequestFactory.java:88) ~[google-http-client-1.30.1.jar:na]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.buildHttpRequest(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:430) ~[google-api-client-1.30.1.jar:1.30.1]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:549) ~[google-api-client-1.30.1.jar:1.30.1]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:482) ~[google-api-client-1.30.1.jar:1.30.1]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:599) ~[google-api-client-1.30.1.jar:1.30.1]
    at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.get(HttpStorageRpc.java:433) ~[google-cloud-storage-1.79.0.jar:1.79.0]
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl$5.call(StorageImpl.java:240) ~[google-cloud-storage-1.79.0.jar:1.79.0]
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl$5.call(StorageImpl.java:237) ~[google-cloud-storage-1.79.0.jar:1.79.0]
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:105) ~[gax-1.46.1.jar:1.46.1]
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:76) ~[google-cloud-core-1.79.0.jar:1.79.0]
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50) ~[google-cloud-core-1.79.0.jar:1.79.0]
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.get(StorageImpl.java:236) ~[google-cloud-storage-1.79.0.jar:1.79.0]
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.get(StorageImpl.java:254) ~[google-cloud-storage-1.79.0.jar:1.79.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.storage.GoogleStorageResource.getBlob(GoogleStorageResource.java:165) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-storage-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:1.1.2.RELEASE]
    at
```

Comment: I couldn't found what where you using to connect to your endpoint? a signed url? a service account? oauth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like an issue regarding authentication. Did you follow the generic 'Spring Cloud GCP Core' [1] configuration?

Check your application.properties [2] (or other configuration) and make sure it contains at least the following properties:

```
spring.cloud.gcp.datastore.project-id=XXX
spring.cloud.gcp.datastore.credentials.location=YYY
```

or choose an other method shown in [1].

[1] https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-gcp/1.1.2.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-gcp.html#spring-cloud-gcp-core

[2] https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/master/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-data-datastore-sample/src/main/resources/application.properties

Answer (score 6):

Thank you Joe. The resource to implement 'Spring Cloud GCP Core' was never mentioned in the tutorials or i overlooked it.

Somehow another account was connected in my Google Cloud SDK on my console. So i used

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

and logged in the right account. Now it works. Thank you.